# how could I change the orders of devices traits

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home, google-assistant

I'm building my own device on google home, I  am wondering if it is possible to order the device's traits to be displayed in a specific order on Nest Hub.
--- e.g,  I would like to display first the toggles then the volume.
see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHRBq.jpg) of my google hub screen, I have the volume at the top then the controls... I would like the control to be first.
Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism for you, as the developer, to set the order of traits.